# how to filter the lines in a buffer after comparing with particular string

Tags: c

I am trying to filter only those lines from the given buffer(1200 lines), whose first token matches with a particular string. Here the strings in the lines are separated by "@" symbol and the lines are separated by "\n".

So, first of all I splitted the strings using strtok() and storing the tokens in an array of pointers.
And then I used compared

```
if(token[0]=="abc.com") print("%s",token[i])
```

Here it is printing only all the lines which starts with abc.com with first token only.

So, can anyone help me how to print the original lines after matching the first token.

```
int len_of_buff; 
int n; 
//char tokens[1024]; 
int ret_code = 1; 
n=0;
len_of_buff = strlen((char *)my_buffer);
//char *tokens[len_of_buff]; 
for(i=n;i<len_of_buff; i++) { 
    char tokens[1024]; 
    tokens[i] = strtok ((char *)my_buffer,"@\n"); 
//if (my_buffer[i] == '\n') my_buffer[i]='\0';     
ret_code=strcmp(tokens[0], "abc.com"); 
if (ret_code==0) {
printf("\n"); 
fprintf(stdout, "%s \n ",(char *)my_buffer+n); 
// fprintf(stdout, "******The buffer is: %d bytes\n",len_of_buff); 
n = i+1; 
break; } }
```

Comment: This `if(token[0]=="abc.com")` isn't a correct way to compare strings in C. Use [`strcmp`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcmp.htm) instead .

Comment: Please show more code.

Comment: @user5424164 Please don't post code in comment section its hard to even read . Please post it along with the question .

Comment: sorry for that. now I have reposted my question.

Comment: I will appreciate if anyone can help me how to do that as I am stuck here.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(token[0]=="abc.com")
```

Simply compares two pointers (one to the constant string, the other to somewhere in your input line. This will *always* return FALSE.

```
if (strcmp (token[0], "abc.com") == 0)
```

Would do the right thing, provided token[0] is a char pointer to your first token.

If you want to print the whole, original line, you need to save it somewhere - strtok destroys the original string during the parsing process.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am successful in printing the whole buffer without using strtok()

Answer (score 0):

now i did it as following and it is working fine.

```
char buffer_copy[1000];
strcpy( buffer_copy, buffer );
char * tokens[1000];
size_t token_count = 0;
char * ptr = tokens[token_count] = buffer_copy;
while( *ptr )
    if( ( *ptr == '@' ) || ( *ptr == '\n' ) )
        *ptr++ = '\0', tokens[++token_count] = ptr;
    else
        ++ptr;

size_t index;
for( index = 0; index < token_count; ++index )
     if( !strcmp( tokens[index], "member" ) )
         printf( "%d: %s  | %s", index, tokens[index], buffer );
```